# Mismatch between version of packages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

So i have a bunch of warning in Visual Studio i would like to get rid of and I don´t know if there is a simple solution to this. I might have mixed .Net Core 3.1 with older .NETFramework. I think that this might be caused by me importing the Identity stuff (Areas.Identity.Pages....).

What is the correct solution to solve this?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData 3.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.   myupload    C:\src\MyUpload\myupload\myupload.csproj    0   
Warning     Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.    myupload    C:\src\MyUpload\myupload\myupload.csproj    0   
Warning     Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.   myupload    C:\src\MyUpload\myupload\myupload.csproj    0   
Warning     Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data 3.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.  myupload    C:\src\MyUpload\myupload\myupload.csproj    0   
Warning     Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers 3.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. myupload    C:\src\MyUpload\myupload\myupload.csproj    0   
Warning     Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.  myupload    C:\src\MyUpload\myupload\myupload.csproj    0   
Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.  myupload    C:\src\MyUpload\myupload\myupload.csproj    1   
Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers 3.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. myupload    C:\src\MyUpload\myupload\myupload.csproj    1   
Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.   myupload    C:\src\MyUpload\myupload\myupload.csproj    1   
Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data 3.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.  myupload    C:\src\MyUpload\myupload\myupload.csproj    1   
Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData 3.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.   myupload    C:\src\MyUpload\myupload\myupload.csproj    1   
Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.    myupload    C:\src\MyUpload\myupload\myupload.csproj    1
```

What I have tried:

**Attempt 1:**

```
Update-Package –reinstall

No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'myupload'.
Executing nuget actions took 0,4 ms
Time Elapsed: 00:00:06.3129712
```

Comment: You'll likely just need to reinstall your packages for the right framework, `Update-Package –reinstall` A package that is installed against an old target framework gets uninstalled and the same package gets installed against the current target framework of the project. then do a clean and rebuild

Comment: Thanks for the tip but nothing happend when i tried that.

No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'myupload'.
Executing nuget actions took 0,4 ms
Time Elapsed: 00:00:06.3129712

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem.

Removing the packages Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers and clean up some references "using" statements in some classes did remove all warnings. Luckily none of that was in use.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should have all project in framework version 4.7.2 as you are working with .net core 3.1